# Excel VBA autofilter: Criteria strings gets converted into a number

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a problem with filtering a date. While autofiltering my formatted string get converted into a number. This is my filterCriteria1 string.

[image]

Here is the code used:

```
days = Array(-5, -10, -15)

For Each d In days

    filterDate = DateTime.DateAdd("d", d, DateTime.Now)
    filterCriteriaDay = CStr(Format(filterDate, "dd"))
    filterCriteriaMonth = CStr(Format(filterDate, "mm"))
    filterCriteriaYear = CStr(Format(filterDate, "yyyy"))
    
    FilterCriteria1 = filterCriteriaMonth & "/" & filterCriteriaDay & "/" & filterCriteriaYear & " 00:00:00"
    
    MsgBox FilterCriteria1

    Stop
    
    
    If d = -5 Then
         ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=" & FilterCriteria1 _
    , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Today
        Stop
    ElseIf d = -10 Then
        
    Else
    
    End If
    

    
Next d
```

Here is how the filter looks after the filter is applied.
[image]

Even, if I just replace the FilterCriteria1 with string "02/03/2023" it still gets converted into a number. And it does not filter at all. Manually putting 45064 (05/18/2023) into filter also does not work.

EDIT: Looks like the filtered data are mix of a dates and strings, but it should still yield some returned values. Equation used `=<date cell> + 1`

[image]

EDIT: After changing `FilterCriteria1 = filterCriteriaMonth & "/" & filterCriteriaDay & "/" & filterCriteriaYear & " 00:00:00"`
to `FilterCriteria1 = filterCriteriaDay & "/" & filterCriteriaMonth & "/" & filterCriteriaYear & " 00:00:00"` Filter is applied as shown below.
[image]

The problem is, that now the dates are not in correct format, so the filter is not working correctly. I will try to refactor the column with dates to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem: 45064 is the numierc value of 2023-05-18

Comment: *"Even, if I just replace the FilterCriteria1 with string "02/03/2023" it still gets converted into a number."* - yes, but does the filter *work*?

Comment: Ok, but if I manually put 05/18/2023 it works, if I left the 45064 in it does not...

Comment: Excel traditionally stores dates (and date-times) as numbers. When receiving a perfectly formatted date as filter criteria, Excel is converting that to the equivalent numeric value for storage. This should work with filtered data. However, if your data is made of strings that *look* like dates, rather than actual dates, it will not. Is your data actually made of date values? Quick way to check, try creating a cell adjacent to a date with formula `=<date cell> + 1`

Comment: They are not infact dates the adjacent cell value with the formula is some random number.. but not at all of the cells, looks like it is a mix... I edited the question.

Comment: Looks like the data is in mm/dd/yyyy format, while your computer is expecting dd/mm/yyyy?  In your image any value that could use the second set of numbers as a month is working, while any value above 12 is returning an error.

Comment: Change: FilterCriteria1 = filterCriteriaMonth & "/" & filterCriteriaDay & "/" & filterCriteriaYear & " 00:00:00" ..........to: FilterCriteria1 = filterCriteriaYear & "/" & filterCriteriaMonth & "/" & filterCriteriaDay & " 00:00:00"

Comment: My computer uses dd/mm/yyyy, but the document is always in mm/dd/yyyy format, I will try to change the criteria.

Comment: Changing the month for a day, puts the string dd/mm/yyyy and applies the filter. Sadly the data stays the same and are not filtered.